# What prior theory and calculation techniques should I review to be strong in my complex analysis computations?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm an undergrad enrolled in complex analysis this semester, and I've realized that while my understanding of the theory isn't too bad, my computation skills are horrendous. I keep losing my place in all of the theory because the professor and author of our text assume a certain level of computational skills in calculus II and perhaps some other classes.

I think that I need to review my calculus computation skills, but I'm not sure if there are any other calculation techniques I should be learning.

Can anyone give me a list of calculation skills/theorems from previous courses I should brush up on to make learning complex analysis less rough?

Thanks